# "error C2078: too many initializers" при инициализации массива символов

Tags: c++

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не получается определить массив? Объявляю массив таким образом:

```
char arr[]={"a", "b"};
```

Получаю такую **ошибку**:

> error C2078: too many initializers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что вы пытаетесь инициализировать элементы массива char[], которые имеют тип char, строковыми литералами "a" и "b", каждый из которых имеет тип char[]. Правильно для инициализации использовать символьные литералы:

```
char arr[] = {'a', 'b'};
```

На всякий случай, cледует заметить, что arr не будет являться валидной C-строкой, т.к. строка должна оканчиваться нулем. Поэтому если вы хотите получить строку, то следует добавить нулевой символ в конец:

```
char arr[] = {'a', 'b', '\0'};
```

или коротко:

```
char arr[] = "ab";
```

Answer (score 2):

Доброго времени суток! Определитесь с тем, что хотите получить:
Массив символов:

```
char arr[] = { 'a', 'b' }; // кавычки одинарные!
```

Или массив строк:

```
char *arr[] = { "a", "b" }; // кавычки двойные!
```